# Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test - can you make R subset different types of treatments when comparing before and after measurements?

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to the R programming, but I am ever learning :)

I want to conduct a paired Wilcoxon Rank Sum test of before and after measurements. My subjects have gotten 4 different types of treatments (i.e. treatment as factor w/ 4 levels). My data is ordinal.

I have a data frame containing 3 columns:

- Before
- After
- Type of treatment

Can I run the wilcox.test while subsetting the different types of treatments?

I ran the wilcox.test as follows:

```
wilcox.test(Before,After,paired=TRUE)
```

how do I edit this code to subset for my types of treatment?

Hope there is someone able to help me... :)

Before | After  | Treatment

------ | ------ | ---------

  2    |   2    |   SH

  2    |   1    |   SH

  2    |   2    |   SH

  1    |   1    |   SH

  2    |   2    |   OH

  2    |   2    |   OH

  2    |   2    |   OH

  2    |   1    |   OH

  2    |   1    |   SA

  2    |   1    |   SA

  1    |   1    |   SA

  2    |   2    |   SA

  2    |   2    |   OA

  2    |   3    |   OA

  1    |   2    |   OA

  2    |   2    |   OA

Comment: Could you provide some data please?

Comment: @dvarelas I have made something that looks like a table in the edited version above. Hope you can use it

Comment: the ranking was set from 1 - 4 (1 being best, 4 being the worst)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` to make a list of your groups and then `lapply` over the list...

```
x <- read.csv(text = "Before|After|Treatment
2|2|SH
2|1|SH
2|2|SH
1|1|SH
2|2|OH
2|2|OH
2|2|OH
2|1|OH
2|1|SA
2|1|SA
1|1|SA
2|2|SA
2|2|OA
2|3|OA
1|2|OA
2|2|OA", sep = "|")

x <- split(x, x$Treatment)
lapply(x, function(g) wilcox.test(g$Before, g$After, paired = T))
```

> $OA
>
> Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
>
> data:  g$Before and g$After V = 0, p-value = 0.3458 alternative
>   hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
>
> $OH
>
> Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
>
> data:  g$Before and g$After V = 1, p-value = 1 alternative hypothesis:
>   true location shift is not equal to 0
>
> $SA
>
> Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
>
> data:  g$Before and g$After V = 3, p-value = 0.3458 alternative
>   hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
>
> $SH
>
> Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
>
> data:  g$Before and g$After V = 1, p-value = 1 alternative hypothesis:
>   true location shift is not equal to 0

Comment: It's working with the split. I'm now having a list of 4 under x :) But I get this error message when using lapply:

Comment: "Error in g$Before : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". When checking g$Before "> is.atomic(g$Before)" I get this message:
"Error: object 'g' not found"

Comment: If you copy and paste all of the code it runs just fine.`g` only exists while `lapply` is running which is why `is.atomic(g$Before)` gives an error. You will need to provide your actual data for me to help, otherwise. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do that.

Comment: I tried it once again on my actual data and Voilá! ;) It worked! Thank you so much! You saved me!